# how to change Vlookup formula to Dlookup with same result

Tags: excel, ms-access, vlookup

I have used Vlookup in Excel to find hostnames corresponding to each Record ID according to KB Number. So basically I have one excel worksheet contains available Record Id and KB number, another contains all the KB number and Hostname, and I need to find the hostname of all Record Id by comparing KB number of both worksheet, I import my final worksheet into access it look as below:
[image]

However, I was informed that I should achieve the same thing using Dlookup which is a confusion to me. I wish I could have some advice on how I should achieve this, I don't mind to achieve that using either two or one table.

Comment: So you want the HostName for a specific RecordID and KBNumber?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, there is no need for a DLookup in this situation. You can simply create a query using your two tables joined on the fields you are comparing.

```
SELECT OtherTable.[Record ID],
OtherTable.[KB Number], 'OR Patches.[KB Number],
Patches.HostName
FROM OtherTable
INNER JOIN Patches
ON OtherTable.[KB Number] = Patches.[KB Number]
```

This will give you all the records in your other table and corresponding matching records in the Patches table based on the KB Number. If you're trying to find a specific Hostname based on a specific Record ID, then you may want to consider using a paramaterized query.